# Looking for a solution to create text files with unique filenames and text with specific format

Tags: c#

I have this piece of code that creates a new text file with a unique filename and writes text with specific format to each file every time one of the events I'm monitoring for takes place.

```
method void recordevent(string msg) 
variables:
string filepath; 
begin 


    filepath = string.format("{0}\{1}_{2}_{3:yyyyMMddhhmmss}_{4}_{5}.txt",     
        iprimarydirectory,     
        filnamplusymtic, 
        gronam,     
        datetime.now,
        castyp,
        numtostr(price,2));

    print(filepath);
    sw = streamwriter.create(filepath);  
    sw.autoflush = true;    
    sw.writeline(msg);      
    sw.close();     
end;



If dtc=false and dtc[1]=true and lastbaronchart and barstatus( 1 ) = 2 then begin 
recordevent(

"group "+ gronam + newline +

"symbol: " + spaces(1) + symtic + spaces(1) + “ended downtrend” + spaces(1) + “case type d” + spaces(1) + numtostr(price,2)" + newline

); 
end;
```

(note: iprimarydirectory, filnamplusymtic, gronam, castyp are just string inputs I use to sort the files into different groups.)

I'm looking for any solution that will let me do the same thing using c# inside the ninjatrader platform.

- That is, dynamically generate one unique text file with a unique name per event. I use several string inputs and variables, date and time from year to second and market price to create filenames. This is to make sure filenames are unique and also that files are sorted by symbol ticker and time the event took place. Files should be unique to each event and should not be modified after they have been created.
- use one of four text templates I have (there are four types of event) to write text inside each file according to the type of event with a specific format combining several string inputs and variables, spaces and line breaks.

This is the only fragment of c# code I have so far.

```cs
 protected override void OnBarUpdate()
        {
            if(CurrentBar % 2 != 0)
                WriteFile("Hello");
        }

        private object lockObj = new object();

        private void WriteFile(string text)
        {
          // lock a generic object to ensure only one thread is accessing the following code block at a time
          lock (lockObj)
          {
              string filePath = @"C:\ntlogs\" + DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyyMMdd HHmmss") + ".txt";
              using (System.IO.FileStream file = new System.IO.FileStream(filePath, FileMode.OpenOrCreate, FileAccess.ReadWrite, FileShare.None))
              {

                byte[] tempstring = new UTF8Encoding(true).GetBytes(text);

                file.Write(tempstring, 0, tempstring.Length);  

                // be sure to flush the buffer so everything is written to the file.
                file.Flush();

                // The "using" block implicitly closes the FileStream object,
                // giving other threads access to the file
              }
          }
```

I need to be able to insert several string inputs like gronam and filnamplusymtic into the filename but I have no idea how to include them. I also need to write text to the files following my templates which include several string inputs, spaces and line breaks, but if I insert anything like + newline + or + spaces(1) insde WriteFile("Hello"); the code won't compile anymore.

I will be really grateful if anyone has any advice.

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to share your problem. Stack Overflow is not a programming nor a course service. What is your goal and your difficulty? What have you done so far? Please try to better explain your issue, your development environment and the data structures, as well as to share more code (no screenshot), images or sketches of the screen, and user stories or scenario diagrams. To help you improve your requests, please read the *[How do I ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)* and **Questions I avoid asking** at the top right.

Comment: What did you try? The snippet isn't in C#, as told by the tag. You could at least put some snippets of what you have tried first.

Comment: thanks.my first question in this forum was a more extensive explanation of this same solution i'm looking for, i included all the code i have there. that question also was downvoted and i was not allowed to post questions for two days, because it was too long and too detailed.
i will try to post the incomplete fragment of c# code i do have.

Comment: You don't say where gronam and the other variables are defined or what their scope is, but the straightforward and clean way would be to pass them into the WriteFile method as parameters. For your second question, can you show the code that doesn't compile?

Answer (score 0):

trying to code can be brutally hard for non-programmers like myself but i have almost made it.

```cs
Smap01                          = 65;
                Numcon                          = 1;
                Pridir                          = @"c:\ntlogs\";
                Symtic                          = @"m2kz9";
                Excide                          = @"globex";
                Gronam                          = @"manadjdt";
                Castyp                          = @"d";
                BarsRequiredToPlot              = 65;
                AddPlot(new Stroke(Brushes.Blue, DashStyleHelper.Solid, 3), PlotStyle.Line, "Sma01li");
            }
            else if (State == State.Configure)
            {
                AddDataSeries(Data.BarsPeriodType.Minute, 1);
            }
        }

        protected override void OnBarUpdate()
        {

        if (BarsInProgress != 0) 
            return;

        if (CurrentBars[0] < 1)
            return;

        if (CurrentBars[0] <= BarsRequiredToPlot) return;

        Clostr = Close[0].ToString("0.########");

         // Set 1
        if (CurrentBar % 2 == 0)
            {
                WriteFile(  

                            "group {Gronam}" + Environment.NewLine +

                            "symbol: {Symtic} started downtrend {Castyp} {Clostr}" + Environment.NewLine

                            );
            }

         // Set 2
        if (CurrentBar % 2 == 1)
            {
                WriteFile(  
                            "group {Gronam}" + Environment.NewLine +

                            "symbol: {Symtic} ended downtrend {Castyp} {Clostr}" + Environment.NewLine

                            );
            }
        }

            private object lockObj = new object();

        private void WriteFile(string text)
        {
          lock (lockObj)
          {
//            + numtostr(Close[0],2)
              string filePath = string.Format(@"{0}ntlogs {1} {2} {3} {4} {5}.txt", Pridir, Symtic, Gronam, DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyyMMdd HHmmss"), Castyp, Clostr);
              using (System.IO.FileStream file = new System.IO.FileStream(filePath, FileMode.CreateNew, FileAccess.ReadWrite, FileShare.None))
              {

                byte[] tempstring = new UTF8Encoding(true).GetBytes(text);

                file.Write(tempstring, 0, tempstring.Length);  

                file.Flush();

              }
          }

        }
```

this indicator does create a unique file with a unique filename every time a market event is observed.

i could still use some help with the two WriteFile sections. below is the text that is being written to the files with this code as i have it:

group {Gronam}

symbol: {Symtic} started downtrend {Castyp} {Clostr}

as should be obvious, i don't want the names of the variables i'm trying to use to be written to the text files, i want the values for said variables.

also, i tried to create a private variable Clostr = Close[0].ToString("0.########"); which i want to use to change a numeric value to string. if i could get it to ¿print? the value with the number of decimals the user could define (sometimes 2, sometimes 4, 6 or 8) that would be magnificent.

very well, thanks, regards.